# Magento 2 : How to upload image from front side

Tags: magento2, php

**Error**

```
"$_FILES array is empty";i:1;s:10336:"#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento217/vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php(161): Magento\Framework\File\Uploader->_setUploadFileId('1.png')
```

**Block File**

```
public function createForm()     
{
    echo "
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Student Form Detail
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id='std_form' name='std_form' action='".$this->getFormSaveAction()."' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
                Enter student name :
                <input type='text' name='std_name' id='std_name' maxlength='15' width='16'/><br/>
                Enter student age :
                <input type='text' name='std_age' id='std_age' maxlength='2' width='3'/><br/>
                Upload student image :
                <input type='file' name='std_img' id='std_img' /><br/>
                <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'/> <br/>
                <a href= '".$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl().'form/fatchdetail/search/'."'> 
                <input type='button' value='Search'/> 
                </a>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    ";
}

public function getFormSaveAction()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/save');
}
```

}

**Controller For Save**

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Detailcommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Detail\Form\Controller\FatchDetail;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $cacheTypeList;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $testimonialFactory;
    protected $forwordFactory;
    protected $adapterFactory;
    protected $uploader;
    protected $filesystem;
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    protected $inlineTranslation;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $_escaper;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_directory;
    protected $_imageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $adapterFactory,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $uploader,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory $imageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $this->_imageFactory = $imageFactory;
        $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
        $this->adapterFactory = $adapterFactory;
        $this->uploader = $uploader;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_escaper = $escaper;
parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('Detail\Form\Model\Form');

        $product->setData('student_name',$post['std_name']);
        $product->setData('student_age',$post['std_age']);

        $base_media_path = 'demo/';


        $uploader = $this->uploader->create(
         ['fileId' => $post['std_img']]
         );

        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
        $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
        $uploader->addValidateCallback('image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $result = $uploader->save(
         $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($base_media_path)
         );
        $this->_redirect('*/*/detail');
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure name of file it is same.

Comment: Block file name = Detail.php and Controller File name =  Save.php @SunilPatel

Comment: i am asking name of that field on form where you want to upload image or any thing?

Comment: yes I check both the name are same(name = std_img)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code

```
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $_filesystem;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem

) {

    this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){

    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);

    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);

    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

    $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)

    ->getAbsolutePath('images/');

    $uploader->save($path);

}
```

Comment: for your field id is std_img

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to provide some clarification here, regarding the $uploader initialization using UploaderFactory.  I was trying to achieve the same thing as OP, and Sunil's answer helped a lot, but I lost several hours being stuck on the value of 'fileId'.  This answer -- as well as all of the other tutorials I followed -- indicates that the value is a string -- either the name of the file or the name of the HTML input element.  But in my case, the value needed to be the file itself, which is an array instead of a string.  So, like this:

```
$uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $file]);
```

Or, to be clear, my case specifically:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
  if(isset($file['name']) && isset($file['error']) && $file['error']==0) {
    try {
     $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $file]);
      ...
    }
```

Honestly, I don't understand why this works, since the $fileId in the Uploader constructor is supposed to be a string... but it does.  If anyone can explain that part, I would be very interested.

Hope this helps someone.